# Correct way to refer to a file in a directory treee

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, path

I have this directory tree:

```
 main_dir
     data_folder
       file.csv
     script_folder
           script.py
```

Inside `script.py`I have:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

What is the correct way to refers to the `file.csv` in the pandas `read_csv`

I don't want to use the full path `"home/user/main_folder/data/file.csv"`

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Does `'../data_folder/file.csv'` work? Generally, the relative paths are relative to the directory you are in when launching the script.

Comment: This stuff is a pain. The proper way of handling it depends on what your project is. If it’s just ‘a script’, then the best option is probably `Path("data_folder") / "file.csv"`, and then to run your script from `main_dir/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where your script is executed (current working directory). To use relative path from your script, use `__file__` variable:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'data_dir'

df = pd.read_csv(data_dir / 'file.csv')
```